# Disable click on ".lg-img-wrap" class in Light Gallery

Tags: html, css, lightgallery

How to disable click on .lg-img-wrap?

I have tried lot of solutions but none seems to work on lightgallery.

**Tried 1**

```
$(".lg-img-wrap").children().unbind('click');
```

**Tried 2**

```
$(".noclick").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Tried 3**

```
pointer-events:none //to a css property
```

I would like to prevent closing of light gallery when user clicks outside the image.

Black margin is visible when image ratio is not same as that of screen size.

Please check image below for reference.
[image: lightbox image]

Light Gallery I am using: https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `closeable: false` to your lightGallery initialization. Here's [their API](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html) describing that feature.

[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/benthon123/pen/YzpPrxg)

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.10.0/css/lightgallery.css" integrity="sha512-I/g40Mx7U2Oepd3iHIpQRqdQGJ3vgdw0ix8LxGxX9zKv1MDizjD6dRcJ3PC1qpyfkj4rikVNcpBKcnmuJWUaTQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.10.0/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#lightgallery').lightGallery({
        closable: false
    }); 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for a quick response.. I tried to look for such configuration parameter before, not sure why I couldn't find one.. I will reward you bount after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".lg-img-wrap").off("click");
```

or

```
$(".lg-img-wrap").prop("disabled",true);
```

or

```
$('.lg-img-wrap"').click(false);
```

I hope it works for you. good work.

Comment: Okay, let me give it a try.

Comment: it did not work. please add light gallery in an html file and try..